# Why is "TRANSFER" colored blue in SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Is `TRANSFER` a keyword or reserved word in MS SQL SERVER ,because when I type this word in SQL server management studio its colour turns blue?

When I checked this word in [Microsoft's list of Reserved Words](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) it was not mentioned there.

Can someone please help me to know when and why colour of words changes in management studio of SQL server.

Comment: Saima, check Aaron Bertrant's answer to this question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22655/why-is-lookup-colored-as-a-function-reserved-word-in-sql-server

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is. Is used by `ALTER SCHEMA` command.

```
ALTER SCHEMA schema_name 
   TRANSFER [ <entity_type> :: ] securable_name [;]

<entity_type> ::=
    {
    Object | Type | XML Schema Collection
    }
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @user2864740, *Is TRANSFER a keyword or reserved word in MS SQL SERVER?*

Comment: @user2864740, it's not in the list of reserved keywords, right. But, it is kind of reserved word from my perspective...

Comment: It's definitely part of a special grammar production, but because it isn't a reserved word it can be used as a column identifier without quotes or qualification.